# Sugestão de criação da tag "prototipação"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tag-específica

Atualmente temos a tag [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo), cuja descrição não bate com o uso que está sendo feito da mesma:

> Na Engenharia de Software, protótipo é um sistema/modelo (um website ou outro software) sem funcionalidades inteligentes (acesso à banco de dados, por exemplo), podendo conter apenas funcionalidades gráficas. Utilizado para fins de ilustração e melhor entendimento, geralmente em reuniões entre a equipe de Análise de Sistemas e o contratante.

A descrição se refere à engenharia de software, mas todas as perguntas com essa tag se referem ao protótipo do JavaScript (i.e. à herança prototípica).

Dada a ambiguidade, e ao fato das perguntas existentes sobre [protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=prot%C3%B3tipo) e [prototipação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=prototipa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) até o momento não terem usado essa tag, minha sugestão é que sua descrição seja modificada para se referir explicitamente à herança prototípica (eu sei que no geral não criamos tags para características individuais de linguagens específicas, mas o conceito de herança prototípica transcende JavaScript, ainda que essa linguagem seja a única [popular] que faça uso do mesmo). A descrição atual seria então movida pra uma nova tag - sugiro [prototipação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototipa%c3%a7%c3%a3o) - que seria aplicada a algumas perguntas relevantes sobre o tema.

Foi sugerido em vez disso usar [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo) para perguntas de prototipação, e [prototype](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype) (que ainda não existe) para perguntas de herança prototípica, mas pessoalmente essa ideia não me agrada (embora não saiba bem o porquê). O que acham?

Comment: Concordo com você. E colocaria prototype como sinônimo de protótipo.

Comment: Concordo que a solução mais adequada párese ser `protótipo` como `prototipação`, apenas salientei sobre o que sera feito com a atual tag `protótipo`.

Comment: Crie respostas `wiki` para votação. :D

Comment: Você tem um exemplo de pergunta sobre prototipação? Precisamos de pelo menos uma pergunta com a tag para "transplantar" o wiki, aí ficamos livre para alterar o texto da tag protótipo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Vou olhar, nas duas pesquisas linkadas tem alguns exemplos em potencial, mas ainda não olhei com calma pra ver se em algum deles caberia a tag.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Não sei se entendi o que quer dizer, parece ser o contrário do que eu estou dizendo (i.e. nós dois concordamos), mas vou fazer o que sugere e colocar respostas wiki, assim facilita das pessoas opinarem a favor e contra.

Comment: O que aconteceu com essa proposta? Estava vendo hoje e esta tudo igual.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Aconteceu que todo mundo (inclusive eu) se esqueceu dela... :P Bom, como já deu bastante tempo, e as pessoas em geral concordaram com a nossa proposta, vou ver se em breve coloco ela em prática, marco a resposta como aceita, e encerramos a questão.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Proposta: `prototipação` para ES, `protótipo` e `prototype` para OO

1. Criar a tag [prototipação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototipa%c3%a7%c3%a3o) para designar o conceito na Engenharia de Software;

   - Exemplos de perguntas que poderiam *talvez* receber essa tag:

     ["O que é uma Linguagem de Prototipação?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97445/215)

     ["Quais são as diferenças entre Wireframe, Protótipo e Mockup?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21677/215)
2. Transferir a descrição atual da tag [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo) pra lá;
3. Alterar a descrição da tag [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo) para designar o conceito na Orientação por Objetos;
4. Manter as perguntas atualmente tagueadas como [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo)  como estão (pois a tag já está sendo usada com esse sentido);
5. (Opcional) Criar a tag [prototype](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype) como sinônima para [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo).

Comment: Nota: eu não posso votar nas minhas próprias respostas, mas é essa proposta que eu apoio, a outra não me agrada.

Comment: A mais adequada : D

Answer (score 0):

### Proposta: `protótipo` para ES, `prototype` para JS

1. Criar a tag [prototype](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype) para designar o conceito de Herança Diferencial tal como aplicada em JavaScript (já que essa é a palavra-chave empregada, em torno da qual giram as dúvidas);
2. Taguear algumas perguntas que usam o conceito de prototipação na Engenharia de Software com a tag [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo);

   - Exemplos de perguntas que poderiam talvez receber essa tag:

     ["O que é uma Linguagem de Prototipação?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97445/215)

     ["Quais são as diferenças entre Wireframe, Protótipo e Mockup?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21677/215)
3. Retaguear todas as demais perguntas de [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prot%c3%b3tipo) para [prototype](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype);
4. Dar uma descrição apropriada para a tag [prototype](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype);
5. Não haveria tag alguma para o conceito genérico de [Herança Diferencial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30718/215) em Orientação por Objetos, já que ela é rara exceto por JavaScript e é pouco discutida (não merecendo uma tag própria).